# How to make rectangle in XAML with different radius for corners?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

How to make rectangle in XAML with different radius for corners?
I need to create it using only "Rectangle" tag, because width will change dynamically and I don't want to play with few figures.

Exmple:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a Border with its CornerRadius instead of Rectangle.

Spec:

```
<Border CornerRadius="uniformRadius"/>
<Border CornerRadius="topLeft,topRight,bottomRight,bottomLeft"/>
```

Example:

```
<Border CornerRadius="10,0,0,10"/>
```

Comment: But how can I set different CornerRadius for different corners? Is it possible?

Comment: keyboardP answer describes how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You can modify its RadiusX and RadiusY properties of the rectangle.

EDIT: Just saw you want different corners to have a different radius. To have a different degree of curvature for each corner, use a `Border's` [CornerRadius](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.cornerradius.aspx) property.
The order is `Top Left, Top Right, Bottom Right, Bottom Left`.

```
CornerRadius="25,25,0,0"
```

Comment: thank you, but Michael S. Scherotter was first, but he not properly described how to use it.

Comment: No problem :). Key thing is you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

I guess border element would be the simplest solution for you. You can do something like this:

```
<Border Width="200" Height="100" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" Background="Brown" Padding="5" CornerRadius="20 0 0 20"/>
```

Not also you can specify the thickness of each edge in BorderThickness.

If you don't like the Border solution, then I guess the only way do it is by using Path element. Or implement a new UIElement.